# Trying to install Emacs JDEE with openjdk 6

Tags: emacs, java, jde

I am trying to get JDE to auto-complete Java code. I'm running Ubuntu and I have the following packages installed:

openjdk-6-doc
openjdk-6-jdk
openjdk-6-jre
openjdk-6-jre-headless
openjdk-6-jre-lib
openjdk-6-source

I installed JDEE "from source" (not from the package manager).
I included the following in my .emacs, as suggested in another thread here (I checked the directories do exist and seem to have the right content installed with the packages above):

```
;;JDEE
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/jdee-2.4.0.1/lisp")

(setq
 jde-bug-debugger-host-address "127.0.0.1"
 jde-bug-jre-home "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
 jde-compile-option-debug (quote ("all" (t nil nil)))
 jde-debugger (quote ("jdb"))
 jde-global-classpath
   (quote ("." "/usr/share/java/" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/"))
 jde-jdk-doc-url "/usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-doc/html/api/index.html"
 jde-jdk-registry (quote (("1.6.0" . "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk")))
 jde-jdk (quote ("1.6.0"))
 jde-regexp-jar-file "/usr/share/java/regexp.jar"
 jde-sourcepath (quote (".")))

(require 'jde)
```

When editing a .java file, functions like M-x jde-compile work fine, local classes appear in speedbar, there is autocompletion for local classes BUT not for : for example if I type the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class foo {
  private String bar;
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.o
  }
}
```

And the cursor is at 'System.o', no completion is suggested, even when I try M-x semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu. (The message says "Cannot find types for "System"").

If I type 'hello.' the menu gives me two sugestions: main or bar

I noticed that all the java (io, lang...) class files are compressed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/src.zip and tried to uncompress it, with no results in emacs.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Wow!  There is someone who still uses JDEE!  Good luck :-)

Comment: any other alternative??? :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [User's guide](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/emacs/jde/html/jde-ug/jde-ug-content.html) in the "Completing Expressions" section you can find the jde-complete function. By default this function is bound to "C-c C-v C-." . Maybe you missed it. :)

Comment: Oh ok! I thought the completion was integrated into cedet!

Comment: @matt Sorry, but now I don't adherent to CEDET and don't really know how it actually supports Java. I've just encountered [this](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/LearningGnuEmacs/0596006489/gnu3-CHP-9-SECT-5.html) article. It may be usefull for you despite the 2004 year.